# Car disappearing

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

my cars and my friends cars are disappearing so this is what happened every thing disappeared In car we got we were missing 5 million both of us is that in car money

Comment: When you say "disappeared" - can you clarify? As in, the car did not stay in a garage that you put it in? Or something else? Also, how was the car acquired?

Answer (score 1):

If you (and your friends) are missing cars in **single player mode (Grand Theft Auto 5)**, then it is by design that if you drive a car before starting a mission and don't retrieve it after the mission, then that car is impounded by the police and you will have to go to police station shown on map to pay the fine and retrieve it, if you don't retrieve it then it will disappear permanently.

If you (and your friends) are missing cars in **multiplayer mode (Grand Theft Auto Online)**, then it is as other answer said, it's most likely that the money used to buy the car originate from money cheats. However do note that your car can also get impounded by police in online mode, so you might want to check that too.

Comment: As far as I know, they do not take vehicles from players (at least not for the past several months/years) even when money glitches were used to acquire said car.

Answer (score 0):

The removal of Vehicles and Money in Xbox One, PS4 and PC means that the money used to buy them was not acquired legally (either by gameplay or Shark Cards).